# KeyError while reading configuration from utf-8 .ini file using configparser

Tags: python, utf-8, ini, configparser

I'm trying to write a python program using PyCharm and Python 3.3.
What I want to do is that my program will copy files from one directory, to one folder or more (depending on the configuration file).

Since some of the directories I am trying to copy to the files are in Hebrew, the ini file is utf-8.

But, when I read the configuration from that file this is what I get:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe C:/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/RecorderMover/RecorderMover.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/RecorderMover/RecorderMover.py", line 77, in <module>
    sourcePath, destPaths, filesToExclude = readConfig()
  File "C:/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/RecorderMover/RecorderMover.py", line 62, in readConfig
    config = config['RecorderMoverConfiguration']
  File "C:\Python33\lib\configparser.py", line 942, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'RecorderMoverConfiguration'
```

RecorderMover.py:

```
def readConfig():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    with codecs.open('RecorderMover.config.ini', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        config.read(f)

    config = config['RecorderMoverConfiguration']

    sourcePath = config['SourcePath']
    destPaths = config['DestinationPaths']
    filesToExclude = config['FilesToExclude']
```

RecorderMover.config.ini:

```
[RecorderMoverConfiguration]
SourcePath=I:\VOICE\A
DestinationPaths=D:\RoseBackup,E:\רוזה
FilesToExclude=20.08.12.mp3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `.read_file()` method on your `config` instance instead:

```
with open('RecorderMover.config.ini', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    config.read_file(f)
```

The `.read()` method treats `f` as a sequence of filenames instead, and as none of the lines could ever be interpreted as a filename, the configuration ends up empty.

Alternatively, pass in the filename and encoding to `.read()` without opening the file yourself:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('RecorderMover.config.ini', encoding='utf-8')
```

If your input file contains a UTF-8 BOM (`\ufeff`, a Microsoft devation from the UTF-8 standard) either create the file using a tool that doesn't add that character (e.g. *not* Notepad), use the `utf_8_sig` codec to open it:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('RecorderMover.config.ini', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: @Ghost93: You created that file with an editor that adds a UTF-8 BOM. That character is redundant in UTF-8 files and should be removed, really.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It worked!

If anyone else wants to know what's BOM - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)